# How can I preload image files for <image>, svg element?

Tags: image, d3.js, svg, preload

Is it possible to preload image files that will be used for `<image>`, which is an svg element?

Using d3, I am adding an image for each data as following:

```
var images= g.append('svg:image')
                    .attr('y',function(d,i){
                        return (yAxisScale(new Date(d.Year, 0, 1, 0)))                      
                    })
                    .attr('x',function(d,i){                    
                        return(xAxisScale(d.Tournament)+30)
                    })
                    .attr("width",function(d,i){                    
                        return imageScale.bandwidth()*6
                    })    
                    .attr("xlink:href",function(d,i){
                        var filename = d.Winner;
                        var position = filename.indexOf("(")
                        if (position != -1)
                            filename = filename.slice(0,position)
                        position = filename.indexOf(":")
                        if (position != -1)
                            filename = filename.slice(position+1,filename.length)
                        filename=filename.replace(/\s/g,'')                     

                        return "/img/" + filename + ".jpg"                          

                    })
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. SVGImage will use the http cached version if available like any other request.

Comment: Could you elaborate how I can do it with d3? From what I understand javascript Image object works with <img>, not <image> elements.

Comment: Both SVGImage and HTMLImage will use http cache when available to load the requested resource. So you can use any preloader available on the internet, it will work, be it based on `<img>` element, XHR requests, iframe object whatever will make an http request to the resource. D3 as little to do in here. The only thing is that you will have to parse your data to extract the correct sources.

Comment: Not quite true.  Specifying `href` might result in the image being pulled from the browser cache but a request still shows up in the browser's Network debugger. On my browser, those requests take around 4ms. That causes a momentary freeze each time a new svg:image element is create...